# Best data structure to use for translation probabilities of two sets of words in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, matrix, nested, nlp

I'm building up probabilities `p(e | f)` that an english word `e` is the translation of a foreign word `f`. I'm using IBM model 1.

What data structure can I use for this in Python? I'm a complete Python beginner, but I can program fairly proficiently. I guess I'm looking for something like a nested dictionary, or a matrix with named columns and rows.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dictionary within a dictionary:

```
dict = {e1: {f1: p1, f2:p2, ...}, e2: {f1: p3, f2: p4, ...}, ...}
```

Alternatively you could use a normal dictionary which uses the concatenation of e and f as keys and the probability as value:

```
dict = {(e1+f1): p1,(e1+f2): p2, ...}
```

Comment: Hey, I ended up using a tuple `(e, f)` as a key.